# CSS extended adjacent selector

Tags: html, css

Is there a selector similar to the adjacent selector that will select non-adjacent siblings?

like:

```css
.one ? .three { color:red; }
```

```html
<div class="one">1</div>
<div class="two">2</div>
<div class="three">3</div>
```

instead of:

```css
.one + .two + .three { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="one">1</div>
<div class="two">2</div>
<div class="three">3</div>
```

Comment: You are looking for the ~ selector

Comment: So which elements do you want selected? One, two and three? Just two? Two and Three?

Comment: @maltray exactly! thanks :) Feel free to post it as answer, ill tag it

Comment: ~ is just a greedy form of +. It seemed to me like you are just wanting `.two` stylized using this method. Question ambiguity needs improving...

Comment: @JamieBarker As described I needed a similar method to the adjacent selector, which supports items in between. Obviously I got my answer in a few minutes, apparently your understanding is incorrect

Comment: Clearly I wasn't the only one that couldn't understand what you were getting at. No matter though, all is fixed. It was your "instead of" code that was misleading, it inferred you were trying to style `.two`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector you are looking for is the `~` selector, which will do the same as the + selector but won't mind what's on the middle.

This code should do the trick:

```
.one ~ .three {}
```

FYI: Recommended reading on this, [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048) was really useful for me a few years ago.